# In Windows Phone 8 App, how can I realize the command "I give you some content if you put a like on my Facebook page"?

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-like

I'm developing a Windows Phone App for 8/8.1. I would like to give to user free content if he puts a "Like" onto the Facebook page of my application.

How can I achieve this effect? I can I be sure that the "Like" is put to the page?

Comment: You are __not allowed__ to do that – “like gating” is explicitly forbidden now by Facebook.

Comment: @CBroe Is it forbidden what Dimistris suggests? To just ask for that and redirect to the page?

Comment: Well _tricking_ users into thinking a like was required is not allowed either. // Just let users like your page if they _want_ to. If they don’t … move on.

Comment: I agree with your opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. Facebook does not allow it. You can't even see who likes your page if he's not a friend of yours.

This, though, is something most users don't know. Adding a webview redirecting them to the page will work most of the time, since the majority of them will like the page anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the user logged in into your app, you can use http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/howtos/fetch-user-data/ and get all likes and verify if your facebook page is not one of them, if so, them bring a popup control suggesting to like your page and when process is completed verify that he now likes your page and then give him access to the feature/content you want to.